# JSON Autocomplete source

Tags: angularjs, json, elasticsearch, search-suggestion

I have been trying to source search suggestions for Elasticsearch to index via crawled data (using Nutch to crawl sites). I'm getting mixed results and after days of testing and tweaking... I'm asking if there might be a better way to go and source suggestions data for ES to index.

I'm using Angular UI Bootstrap [typeahead](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/typeahead) to implement this and really like how you can have custom templates for the items and the dropdown - great stuff there. I've noticed that the last 2 examples there, for the custom templates, use a `JSON` source INSTEAD of `$http` or `$q` service.

Can you even customize the search suggestions and the dropdown if you DO NOT use a JSON source? OR is it better to just use a JSON source for suggestions initially?

I was even thinking of having Nutch crawl a JSON file to make indexing into ES easier...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually [wrote blog](http://www.bilyachat.com/2015/07/search-like-google-with-elasticsearch.html) how I did autocomplete. So idea was that i had content and i want autocomple on that. That solution is not perfect on huge data set but it could be quick and nice solution on beginning

Comment: nice blog post, thank you. I'm starting to think that its not really about the data source, but, really on how you process the actual text. ES responses are JSON, so it would really be the same thing. Its really more about processing the text in the data correctly

Comment: would you agree with my first comment?

Comment: No its more than text. ES uses analyzers this is the way how you split text. Yes responses are JSON but its just for simplify it. Also again about what i wrote is that you analyze your text and at the same time you have doing 2 things one for autocomplete second is for actual search